# JNI OpenSSL RSA Decryption not working properly

Tags: java, c++, openssl, java-native-interface, rsa

Encryption seems to work fine, but when I start decryption I get wrong output. Keys are given in PEM and length is 2048.

Here are the methods that are called from Java

```
String public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
            "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAm1AThUE8dUz6x5DeDK3J\n" +
            "SKcBbqFVtplHCdf+036+2tZ1RmHcwsKZ6AF4dtCQ/8n+2lMQgdfWSe+gKEp2lIh0\n" +
            "YQUxgQneLXGzvsEjbFVLgxSdLnEfuZrJsNC3J9LHlnvwYYvBQGaSVCx7WhvxFyDC\n" +
            "BJ7SlpjSzVY9yduxRAHKYnsFRwKgEW15N3VYbspd/LTexNHXTbuzQ968wZbWd5rX\n" +
            "qHejM9pFEQsxqBq7uIk3eFvDMZzyi47NaM9eRHX6LyDF4CtL6SL9UKRTnMCrNpDh\n" +
            "WfxaC6xbMf4tf242Bk0TGe8mK6gH5baUs4C14Tq87yUkC9IVMegNlki89nsT5uRX\n" +
            "swIDAQAB\n" +
            "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    String private_key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
            "MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAm1AThUE8dUz6x5DeDK3JSKcBbqFVtplHCdf+036+2tZ1RmHc\n" +
            "wsKZ6AF4dtCQ/8n+2lMQgdfWSe+gKEp2lIh0YQUxgQneLXGzvsEjbFVLgxSdLnEf\n" +
            "uZrJsNC3J9LHlnvwYYvBQGaSVCx7WhvxFyDCBJ7SlpjSzVY9yduxRAHKYnsFRwKg\n" +
            "EW15N3VYbspd/LTexNHXTbuzQ968wZbWd5rXqHejM9pFEQsxqBq7uIk3eFvDMZzy\n" +
            "i47NaM9eRHX6LyDF4CtL6SL9UKRTnMCrNpDhWfxaC6xbMf4tf242Bk0TGe8mK6gH\n" +
            "5baUs4C14Tq87yUkC9IVMegNlki89nsT5uRXswIDAQABAoIBAQCYztBl6ylwv6x9\n" +
            "bSsLjnDb6nSeRF3wqh4asUknDSz6YsY/2Uk61fxXKBs9yzbec/8rD07OcW2EkR8i\n" +
            "hSDmQts+Gb37F5phW91dcOlJTSJedYmwh9yO4JxQOwn5RIjaplZ7ouUgV8rgxmMW\n" +
            "5Sbvemtp4FmRkgrVvGROlrhyENDu0lJzPtVks8XA1Re+CrOinhTCkISChqq/sHVC\n" +
            "sJfsI6OFHzk0Oexnh0sIG5MfaMNFp4Mh38UhrXFBJ6cIBuveEGzzED+AB6O30j3k\n" +
            "XT2pQbjCJcpekfpzfcW1VRfebLIgB+2mVjSleMKgA7ImyXOg4DCJiLWLulgOKmiE\n" +
            "x7qH684BAoGBAM1onwWBR3ERui4p22dNEoZ2tOygzEJKzhjsC1tRDAyO8Gr4QWNk\n" +
            "fNt/+8+gjJkMkkoKtjaqPrOdclhdPVCyQWvJt5ZAyAv0J7HDbZU8uShAOJI4eCpi\n" +
            "G2Xf20S0v84V12MEriWKZTmXUyWWKR87XkLTcVLCyfMTqPR1gMtHfpJpAoGBAMGQ\n" +
            "0lrFeNM2xqD7fZE/465wxp+kYPf/sMNkk6IqxJljtnzjWbySDU9csSwlN03Q36vu\n" +
            "/TGFIUWx2uTvjRHGEPvOC9agEZ8p9kHWrQb1ZgICpd/yWEy9nze66OayN3JyxkVR\n" +
            "pg2R5RRfnWuI9U6CyPhuZlptqDBUHXhG2kVB3Z27AoGBALYT0CpED3zl1uBG0CqA\n" +
            "gjRZE0VRv93fi1NCIUr/y6tyJSDdELE3CQpVJ3RDf33HTAF//0bzoAL9RLeZZtma\n" +
            "OS1/sFHq+KjH80u6zO9l1UcdrkfG8JW5Q0oJpccAZakbaUJniqrSQ6pKPjTqJ2d8\n" +
            "67BW13QiIHts6O5RHiqTJFpJAoGBAJEfMgbqDJdWdv8U7mSq4NnVJaVlCWqF4hHs\n" +
            "Yx9vLyzNbHEfxxSw75ezqAWv9VG7KybtrBindnWZTcLcswhDVlJjfc6w/eU2AbIE\n" +
            "8H7KF2ukbpaDTJ5kgG25DYqAzT9aO7qW54c+/eATe6O28CuntGNF6ikcE8AAIIQf\n" +
            "ot/P7QanAoGADQ5hDdPaq+wSFhYoeh//QfXrkbIcNl18ienY5Sn4jDrNgkkxghdc\n" +
            "WV3biTqIGMf15CI+//dSShbzI7nyoYQ8bl6HsFbEnGyS95PySdF6gUhsPKG83Ih2\n" +
            "SftvM2TzsO9D8XemkOHNwayPMN6YQA3SDZTZNNv3LYD7NkqhRQI0YUo=\n" +
            "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

    public native byte[] publicencryptRsa(String key, byte[] plainText);
    public native byte[] privatedecryptRsa(String key, byte[] encText);
byte[] plainText = "utnznxckymtyhedtumwtswlxgqkibutnznxckymtyhedtumwtswlxgqkibutnznxckymtyhedtumwtswlxgqkib1".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : plainText) {
            sb2.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: plainText = " + sb2.toString());
            //byte [] keyData = "eQg2MDbk3uUtRhMw".getBytes();
//        byte [] encryptedText = encryptAes256(keyData, plainText);
//        byte [] decryptedText = decryptAes256(keyData, encryptedText);
          byte [] encText = publicencryptRsa(public_key, plainText);
            sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : encText) {
                sb2.append(String.format("%02X", b));
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: encText = " + sb2.toString());
          byte[] decBa = privatedecryptRsa(private_key, encText);
        sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : decBa) {
            sb2.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: decBa = " + sb2.toString());
```

Methods from .cpp file

Structures

```
RSA * createRSApub(std::string sKey) {
   
     RSA *rsa = nullptr;
     BIO *keybio; //  BIO_new( BIO_s_mem() );
     keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(sKey.c_str(), sKey.length());

    if (keybio == nullptr) {
        printf( "Failed to create key BIO");
        return nullptr;
    }
    else  rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, nullptr,nullptr, nullptr);

    BIO_free(keybio);

    return rsa;
}
RSA * createRSApriv(std::string sKey) {
    RSA *rsa = nullptr;
    BIO *keybio;
    keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(sKey.c_str(), sKey.length());

    if (keybio == nullptr) {
        printf( "Failed to create key BIO");
        return nullptr;
    }
    else rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, nullptr,nullptr, nullptr);
  
    return rsa;
}
```

Encryption

```
Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_publicencryptRsa(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring key,
                                                       jbyteArray plain_text) {
      jboolean isCopy;

    unsigned char *key_data = (unsigned char *) (env)->GetStringUTFChars(key, &isCopy);
    std::string sKey((char*) key_data);
    int key_data_len = strlen((char*)key_data);


    int plainText_len = env->GetArrayLength(plain_text);
    jbyte* temp = env->GetByteArrayElements(plain_text,&isCopy);
    unsigned char* plainText;
    plainText = (unsigned char *) temp;


    if(nullptr == plainText)
        return nullptr;

    LOGI("The data to encrypt is : %s", plainText);

    unsigned char chEncryptedData[4098] = {};
    int iResult = RSA_public_encrypt(plainText_len, (unsigned char*)plain_text, chEncryptedData, createRSApub(sKey), RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);

//    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, inData, cData);

// If encryption fails, returns nullptr string, else returns encrypted string
    if(-1 == iResult) {
        char *chErrMsg = (char*)malloc(256);
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), chErrMsg);
        LOGE("The data Encryption failed due to the reason : %s", chErrMsg);
        free(chErrMsg);
        return nullptr;
    }
//    for(int i = 0; i < 255; ++i)
//        LOGD("The Encrypted data is[%d] : %c", i, chEncryptedData[i]);

    jbyteArray EncryptedByteArray = env->NewByteArray(iResult);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(EncryptedByteArray, 0, iResult, (jbyte *) chEncryptedData);

    return EncryptedByteArray;
}
```

Decryption

```
Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_privatedecryptRsa(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                       jstring private_key,
                                                       jbyteArray enc_text) {
    jboolean isCopy;
    unsigned char *key_data = (unsigned char *) (env)->GetStringUTFChars(private_key, &isCopy);
    std::string sKey((char*) key_data);
    int key_data_len = strlen((char*)key_data);

    int encText_len = env->GetArrayLength(enc_text);
    jbyte* a = env->GetByteArrayElements(enc_text,&isCopy);
    const unsigned char* encText;
    encText = (unsigned char *) a;

    unsigned char chDecryptedData[4098] = {};

    int result = RSA_private_decrypt(256,encText, chDecryptedData, createRSApriv(sKey), RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);

    if(-1 == result) {
        char *chErrMsg = (char*)malloc(256);
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), chErrMsg);
        LOGE("The data Decryption failed due to the reason : %s", chErrMsg);
        free(chErrMsg);
        return nullptr;
    }

//    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
//        LOGD("The Decrypted data is[%d] : %c", i, chDecryptedData[i]);

    jbyteArray DecryptedByteArray = env->NewByteArray(result);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(DecryptedByteArray, 0, result, (jbyte *) chDecryptedData);

    return DecryptedByteArray;
}
```

Here's out
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZWTE.png)

I don't know where the problem actually is, both keys are valid and `RSA_private_decrypt`  returns correct length of plain_text, but wrong characters.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: I have no idea where that output is coming from, it doesn't appear in any of the code you've shown. The `decBa` output just looks like a section of memory, maybe the processor stack. It definitely isn't the output from an incorrect RSA decryption.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk-Strike that output goes directly from Log.d

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just using the Java cryptography APIs?

Comment: Your decryption call doesn't use encText_len but hardcodes 256 instead.

Comment: @Botje encryption output length is 256, if I use encText_len when I try to decrypt it says that length is too large, that's why it's hardcoded like that.

Comment: @Botje and yes, my task is to learn how openssl rsa works in c++, can't use Java instead.

Comment: The size of the array is directly derived from the output of `RSA_private_encrypt`, which is literally documented as "this is how many bytes of ciphertext were produced" and yet you replace that with a hardcoded number and expect it to work?

Comment: @Botje `RSA_public_encrypt` always produces 256 bytes of ciphertext in my case and I had to hardode this number as I said above.

Comment: @Botje and when `RSA_private_decrypt` is called it returns correct value of plaintext length but wrong characters. That's why I don't understand what is happening, how it knows the length, but decrypted message characters are a complete mess.

Comment: If the length of the java array is somehow wrong then it stands to reason that the contents might also be wrong! Are the contents of the native byte array identical to what your java log reports?

Comment: @Botje yes, they're identical.

Comment: Why would you use JNI for any of this when Java already supports it all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this call:

```
    int iResult = RSA_public_encrypt(plainText_len, (unsigned char*)plain_text, chEncryptedData, createRSApub(sKey), RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
```

The variable `plain_text` is your `jbyteArray` input variable. You should pass `plainText` instead, which is a `const char *`.
In this case the cast masked the problem, and honestly I'm surprised it did not crash your JVM.